# Running MSIL inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, cil

We have Visual Studio 2005.

I can successfully run MSIL programs from the command line using "ilasm".

I would like to be able to run these inside VS.

From other posts and searches, I gather you need to create a "Console Application" type of project? (They allude to the fact that VS can handle MSIL but I can't find any specific "how to".)

"Console Application" gives the standard Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

    namespace AddNumbers
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I then add my .il file (which adds two numbers) to the project. The project builds successfully and when I run it it does nothing and the breakpoints that I set in the .il file are not triggered. Not surprising because the .il file is not being called.

Can some please provide a step-by-step approach to getting this to work?

I'd also like to know what namespace I need to add to the .il file and also if it is possible to pass parameters to the .il file and (if so) how?

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of ILASM MSBuild task.

You would need to enable the line numbers and debugging options for ILASM.

And here is a [complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask.generatefullpathtotool(VS.80).aspx), courtesy of MSDN.

Comment: I really hate it when people link to google as though it were an answer and then the number one result for said search is the stackoverflow question that wasn't actually answered because you just posted a google link.